# How to debug network API in flutter

Tags: php, flutter

Please anyone help me to check the code. The web call is not made. I checked the future function is working well with the other working working code. Another doubt, can I use two http.post in a single future function? One to only post data not to get, and another one to use both post and get data.

```
Future<String> saveTime() async {
var usagetime = 5;
    if (usagetime >= 0) {
      var savetime = {
        'user_id': 120, 
        'app_id': 1,
        'usage_duration': 200,
      };
      var url2 =
          'http://192.168.43.55:8080/php/save_usage_duration.php';

      var response = await http.post(url2, body: savetime);

      var message1 = jsonDecode(response.body.toString());
      print(message1);
      if (message1 == 'ok') {
        Constants.prefsSaveTime.setInt("usage_time", 0);
        Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
          content:
              Text("Your previous usage time has been saved successfully."),
        ));
      } else {
        Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
          content: Text(
              "Previous data not saved, please inform AA Store developer."),
          backgroundColor: Colors.redAccent,
          duration: Duration(seconds: 5, milliseconds: 500),
        ));
      }
     
    }
}
```

And here is my PHP code

```
 <?php
 include ("includes/conn.php"); //$conn
 include ("includes/datetime.php");  //$date $time
 
 $user_id = $_POST["user_id"];
 $app_id = $_POST["app_id"];
 $usage_duration = $_POST["usage_duration"];

//  $user_id = 120;
//  $app_id = 1;
//  $usage_duration = 5532;

 $sql = "INSERT INTO `save_usage_duration`(`duration_id`, `user_id`, `app_id`, `usage_duration`, `usage_date`, `usage_entry_timing`) VALUES (' ','$user_id','$app_id','$usage_duration','$date','$time')";

 if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
  $success='ok';
  echo json_encode($success);    
} else {

$fail = 'fail';
 echo json_encode($fail);   
}
?>
```

Comment: Now whats the problem? did you get any error? let me know.

Comment: no any error message. I found the problem is that it is not accepting any integer value in the data to be sent to web in http.post. It is accepting only string value. Do you have any idea to send integer value? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You are sending a `Map` `savetime` which contain value of integers.

You should send a `jsonObject` in your `body`,

So use `jsonEncode()` to convert yoyr map to `jsonObject`

Replace this line

`var response = await http.post(url2, body: savetime);`

With

`var response = await http.post(url2, body: jsonEncode(savetime));`

Comment: Are you sure, jsonEncode(savetime) works fine. It is not working at me. Do I need to change any php side change?

Comment: Try to send `string` instead of `int` and when you getting the body in your `php script` then convert the `string` into `int` and use int value in your need.